# Определение ID ячейки ( ajax + php )

Tags: ajax, php, select

Всем привет.

```
        $tasks = '';
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `tasks` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10");
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $tasks .= '
                <img src="images/'.getStatusIcon( $row['status'] ).'.png"> 
                '.$row['time'].' 
                '.$row['task'].' 
                '.$row['whom'].'    
                <select name="selectid" id="selectid">
                    <option value="0">- Статус задачи -</option>
                    <option value="2">Выполнено</option>
                    <option value="3">Отклонено</option>
                </select>                               
                <br />
            ';
        }
        echo $tasks;
```

Сам селектор:

```
            $("#selectid").change( function() {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "engine.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        typeid: 3,
                        ajaxid: id
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        $(this).val('Успешно выполнено');
                        loadTasks();
                    }
                });
            });
```

Необходимо, чтобы при выборе статуса задачи, в базу отправлялся запрос с новым номером статуса. Но как сделать, чтобы он присваивался к той строке, на которой выбран селектор?

Выглядит это вот так:

Время — Задача — Селектор (и так 5 последних значений выводится из базы)

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: не on('change',function().....) ???

Answer (score 1):

Подрисуйте select'у в разметке какую-нибудь мета-информацию(metaid например) об id строки, к которой он относится, получайте её как $(this).attr('metaid') и передавайте в $.ajax, а под это дело исправьте логику на сервере в вашем engine.php
PS: Кстати, нехорошо, когда в dom будет несколько элементов с одинаковым id.